# Can I add Lightning-Core to bitcoin-qt full node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, linux, core-lightning

I am interested in running lightning core, but the instructions say Bitcoind is required. I am running a full bitcoin-qt node on Linux Mint Ubuntu. Will lightning core work with qt or, if not, is there  a workaround or some documentation on how to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about [Core Lightning](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning), based on their [documentation](https://docs.corelightning.org/docs/beginners-guide), it requires `bitcoind`. For documentation on getting `bitcoind` up and running try [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#what-is-a-full-node). And for core lightning [here](https://docs.corelightning.org/docs/beginners-guide) (same link as above).

Answer (score 0):

`bitcoin-qt` is really just bitcoin-core so you should be able to use it for your lightning node. 
You'll need to make the rpc and zmq interfaces of the bitcoin node available to your lightning node, check the documentation of the LN node that you use to find out how to configure that.